# How can I create a label text with shadow?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm trying to create a label text with a shadow created automatically by the system. In iOS I know that you can use an Attributed style for the label, but in OS X I can't find this option. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with Core Animation (a.k.a. `CALayer`). Views in iOS are layer-backed by default, but `NSView` on Mac OS X are much older and requires you to turn on layer manually.

The easiest way is to go to the View Effects Inspector (`Cmd + Alt + 8`):

[image: View Effects Inspector]

If you want to add the shadow programmatically:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(5,5)
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 5
    shadow.shadowColor = NSColor.blackColor()

    myLabel.superview?.wantsLayer = true
    myLabel.shadow = shadow
}
```

Comment: @matt *"I'm trying to create a label text with a shadow..."* Plus, when you set the offset and blur radius small, there isn't a difference between the two

Comment: Thank you so much  Code Different, very clear. @matt, sorry for the confusion, my question was not so clear, anyway the answer of Code Different solved my problem.